# Allowing Chart.js to work with jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, charts, chart.js

On my page I have jQuery creating tabs, and I have Chart.js creating a line chart. They both work fine, except I cannot make Chart.js show the line chart inside a jQuery tab. I don't understand what it is about jQuery tabs that could be preventing the chart to display.

The only error I get from Chrome is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null" referring to line 64.

How do I go about making this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Chart.js stuff-->
    <script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
    <style>
            canvas{
            }
    </style>

    <!--jQuery/jQuery UI files-->
    <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>


    <!--To enable jQuery elements-->
    <script>
    $(function()
    {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    });
    </script>



</head>

<body>  
    <script>
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                                {
                                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                                        data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                                },
                                {
                                        fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                                        strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                        pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                                        data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
                                }
                        ]

                }

        var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);

        </script>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="middle">

        <div class="container">
            <main class="content">
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>                        

                    </ul>


                    <div id="tabs-1">
                        <!--Trying to display the chart here is not working-->
                        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabs-2">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </main><!-- .content -->
        </div><!-- .container-->


    </div><!-- .middle-->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
canvas{
        }
/***   tabs   ****/
.etabs { margin: 0;
padding-left:20%; }

.etabs li
{display:inline-block;
width:auto;
padding:0 3% 2% 3%;
text-align:center;

}
.tab { display: inline-block;
zoom:1;
display:inline;
background:url(../images/li_border.fw.png) no-repeat right; 
height:23px;

}
.tab a { font-size: 20px;
line-height: 2em;
display: block;
outline: none; 
color:#D80000;
font-size:20px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.tab a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
.tab.active { color:#D80000;

 position: relative; 
 border-color: #666; }

.tab a.active { 
color:#0085B2; }

.tab-container .panel-container { background: #fff;
border: solid #666 1px;
padding: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
}

/***   tabs   ****/
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
<ul class='etabs'>
<li class='tab'><a href="#history">Chart</a></li>
<li class='tab'><a href="#business">Bar chart</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="history" class="heig">
<h1>bar chart</h1>
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>

</div>
<div id="business" class="heig">
<h1>pie chart</h1>
<canvas id="canvaspie" height="450" width="450"></canvas>

</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.easytabs.js"></script>
<script src="Chart.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ $('#tab-container').easytabs(); });
</script> 
<script>

var barChartData = {
labels : ["Pass","Fail"],
datasets : [
{
fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
data : [65,0]
},
{
fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
data : [0,47]
}
]

}

var myLine=new     Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);
</script>
<script>

var pieData = [
            {
                value: 30,
                color:"#F38630"
            },
            {
                value : 50,
                color : "#E0E4CC"
            },
            {
                value : 100,
                color : "#69D2E7"
            }

        ];

var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvaspie").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here i have used etabs jquery to create tabs and inserted canvas tag in tab content div. it is working fine with chart.js.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer in a different related question in [ChartJS charts not generating within tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29430173/441878) with example code and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow3n/3jkdzv3d/). I'm not using jquery.tabs but I was having the same problem with tabs I made myself. I realized the issue is that with display:none chartjs doesn't know the size of the div to render the chart. The ^ fiddle makes use of two fixes actually: using jquery.hide()/show() instead and temporarily hiding the area with a cover while they render (which I found was necessary in large pages).

The trick is to hide each tab as soon as you render the chart. Again, using tabs I made myself but this should fix your issue too if you're willing to adjust how you show/hide tabs.

The business (full code on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow3n/3jkdzv3d/))

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart1').getContext('2d');
var chart1 = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data1);
$('#tab1').hide();

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');
var chart2 = new Chart(ctx).Line(data2);
$('#tab2').hide();

$('#tab1_btn').on('click',function(){ 
    $('#tab1').show(); 
    $('#tab2').hide() 
})
$('#tab2_btn').on('click',function(){ 
    $('#tab1').hide(); 
    $('#tab2').show() 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. The trick is generate the chart when the tab activated.

```
var chartIsShow = false; 
$(function() {
    $( "#Tabs1" ).tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            if(chartIsShow === false) {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
                window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(chart_data,{ animation : false, responsive : true });
                chartIsShow = true;
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

download customized jquery-ui.js file and check minimum things (only tabs) and uncheck all other at http://jqueryui.com/download/ and include this js file instead of yours on this page